# leaderboard ranking using LINQ rank number and same point

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have the table as follow in my database: 
**User Table** 
UserID
Name
Point

What i intend to do:

```
| Rank |  Name |  Point  |
| 344  | UserA |  2000   |
| 345  | UserB |  1500   |
| 345  | UserC |  1500   |
| 347  | UserD |  1200   |
| 348  | UserE |  1000   |
| 349  | UserF |  1000   | <-- targeted user
| 350  | UserG |  900    |
| 350  | UserH |  800    |
| 352  | UserI |  700    |
| 353  | UserJ |  600    |
```

What i have tried:

```
int point = 1000;
var top6 = db.User.Where(p => p.Point >= point).OrderBy(p => p.Point).Take(6);
var bottom4 = db.User.Where(p => p.Point < point).OrderByDescending(p => p.Point).Take(4);

var leaderboard = top6.Union(bottom4).OrderByDescending(p => p.Point);
```

What is the outcome currently?

```html
|  Name |  Point  |
| UserA |  2000   |
| UserB |  1500   |
| UserC |  1500   |
| UserD |  1200   |
| UserE |  1000   |
| UserF |  1000   | <-- targeted user
| UserG |  900    |
| UserH |  800    |
| UserI |  700    |
| UserJ |  600    |
```

What still unsolved?

- Assign global ranking as shown
- Condition where there is a tie in the ranking

What is the problem I having?
- Do not know how to assign global ranking to the user.
- Do not know how to resolve tie condition to the rank. when tie, the rank should be same

Comment: Where do you get 344 from in your rank column? Also, what is your logic to resolve a tie?

Comment: @shree.pat18 the 344 is global ranking. The user ranks 344 out of all the user in the database. The leaderboard display the nearest top 5 and bottom 4 of the targeted user(User F). The logic to resolve a tie is based on the username in alphabetical order

Comment: You need to tell the conditions why/how you are selecting the target user. At this point just do a single on rank or name.

Comment: I voted up because you did really well with your sections (including your schema, expected result, and attempt), but it would help if you could be a little more clear with what you're looking for from us. A couple other people have hinted at this, but essentially we're currently given a result without an explanation. What problems are you having assigning global ranking?

Comment: @peer the user is determined by their id when they log in into the system and the leaderboard will only be displayed for authenticated user. Could you elaborate "do a single on rank or name"? I am having problem on assigning the global ranking as shown above and to resolve tie condition.

Answer (score 1):

//EDIT:
Linqpad Instant Share to reproduce it:
http://share.linqpad.net/urtpc9.linq

I've gone a slightly different approach to shree.pat18. Instead of generating a list and zipping it, I've used the overloaded `Select()` method to generate an index, after grouping the results, to deal with Tie in points.

Code from LinqPad:

```
void Main()
{
    var players = new List<Player>()
    {
        new Player() {Name ="UserA", Points=2500},
        new Player() {Name ="UserB", Points=2400},
        new Player() {Name ="UserC", Points=2300},
        new Player() {Name ="UserD", Points=2200},
        new Player() {Name ="UserE", Points=2100},
        new Player() {Name ="UserF", Points=2000},
        new Player() {Name ="UserG", Points=1900},
        new Player() {Name ="UserH", Points=1800},
        new Player() {Name ="UserI", Points=1800},
        new Player() {Name ="UserJ", Points=1700},
        new Player() {Name ="UserK", Points=1600},
        new Player() {Name ="UserL", Points=1500},
        new Player() {Name ="UserN", Points=1300},
        new Player() {Name ="UserM", Points=1300},
    };

    var TargetPoints = 1000;

    var RankedPlayers =  players.OrderByDescending(p => p.Points)
                                .GroupBy (p => p.Points)
                                .Select ((grp, i) => new {
                                    Rank = i,
                                    Players = grp.OrderByDescending (g => g.Name)
                                })
                                .Dump();



}
public class Player
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Points { get; set; }
}
```

Output in LinqPad:

[image]

Comment: Interesting approach!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   int point = 1000;          
   var ranks = Enumerable.Range(1,db.User.Count);
   var result = db.User.OrderByDescending(x => x.points).ThenBy(x => x.Name).Zip(ranks, (x,y) => new {x.Name, x.Point, rank = y});
   var top6= result.Where(x => x.Point>= point).OrderBy(x => x.Point).Take(6);            
   var bottom4 = result.Where(x => x.Point< point).OrderByDescending(x => x.Point).Take(4);
   var leaderboard = top6.Union(bottom4).OrderByDescending(x => x.Point).ThenBy(x => x.Name);
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/GFG49040)

Start by generating an ordered list, which we will use as our global ranks. Zip it with the appropriately ordered list of users. The output of the zipping step is a collection of anonymous objects which include a rank field. Then, just use the returned collection along with your logic to get the top, bottom and combined results.